# Find all elements but remove duplicate by class name

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippet of my script below

```
$(this).find("span a").each(function () {
                   target.append("<tr><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td><a href='#'>TEXT</a></td></tr>");
```

Sometimes , 2nd and 3rd instances of the same span a are added to the webpage. So my script is also duplicating those instances. I need a way to a) find the first class name or b)remove duplicates. Below is an example where .franchise_0001 is duplicated 3 times. and 0002 twice. I need to find all , then remove duplicates i assume, but not sure how to do this.

So is there a way to find all span a , then is class is the same remove?

```
<span><a class="franchise_0001"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0002"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0003"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0004"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0005"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0006"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0007"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0008"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0009"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0001"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0001"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0002"></a></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a done flag like

```
var clazz = {};
$(this).find("span a").each(function () {
    var className = this.className;
    if (clazz[className]) {
        return
    }
    clazz[className] = true;
    target.append("<tr><td>" + this.outerHTML + "</td><td><a href='#'>TEXT</a></td></tr>");
})
```

Comment: I updated your fiddle and all duplicates are being shown - http://jsfiddle.net/3w4ymc3t/5/

Comment: @MShack do you want the duplicate to be restricted across all tables... or inside each table

Comment: Arun , i must be adding it to my existing script incorrectly , can you add that so i can check it out - here is my full script - http://jsfiddle.net/3w4ymc3t/22/

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering `span a` by populating an array with `span a` `className` within `.map()` , chaining `.each()` to array of unique elements returned from `.map()`

```
    var res = [];
    var arr = $("span a").map(function(i, el) {
        return $.inArray(el.className, res) === -1 
               ? res.push(el.className) 
                 && $("." + el.className + ":first")[0] 
               : null;
    })
    .each(function() {
      target.append("<tr><td>" 
                    + $(this)[0].outerHTML 
                    + "</td><td><a href='#'>TEXT</a></td></tr>")
    });
```

```js
var res = [];
var target = $("table tbody");
var arr = $("span a").map(function(i, el) {
    return $.inArray(el.className, res) === -1 
           ? res.push(el.className) 
             && $("." + el.className + ":first")[0] 
           : null;
})
.each(function() {
  target.append("<tr><td>" 
                + $(this)[0].outerHTML 
                + "</td><td><a href='#'>TEXT</a></td></tr>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<span><a class="franchise_0001"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0002"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0003"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0004"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0005"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0006"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0007"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0008"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0009"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0001"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0001"></a></span>
<span><a class="franchise_0002"></a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using eq(0) in place of each will do it.

```
$(this).find("span a").eq(0)(function () {
               target.append("<tr><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td><a href='#'>TEXT</a></td></tr>");
```

Comment: that removes all span a , but the 1st one. I need all but duplicates of same class names

Comment: Okay, sorry, I misread the question.  But, can you count the span a elements then loop through them, setting the value of .eq(x) in the loop?

Comment: Can we see more of your code?  What is the 'this" calling the function?